# Rails : Find with deep Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some models :

ad.rb

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base    

  belongs_to :seller, polymorphic: true

  scope :published, -> { where(state: "published") }

end
```

car.rb

```
class Car < Ad

end
```

dealership.rb

```
class Dealership < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :agent
  has_many :cars, as: :seller

end
```

agent.rb

```
class Agent < User

  has_one :dealership, dependent: :destroy

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ads, as: :seller
  has_many :subscriptions

  def has_valid_subscription?
    !Subscription.valid(self.id).blank?
  end

end
```

I know that there's a lot of polymorphism... But I try to keep databases simple as possible.
I clean all model to focus on problem.

I try to get all Ads who has a seller with a user with a valid subscription !

But there is 2 levels of association between my model... And I can't get it !

can you show me the way to do it ?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `seller_user` association to Ad model

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :seller_user, :foreign_key => :seller_id, :class_name => "User", conditions: { ads: { seller_type: "User"}}
  scope :published, -> { where(state: "published") }
end
```

Now you can do

```
Ad.all.collect{|ad| ad.seller_user && ad.seller_user.has_valid_subscripion?}
```

If you just need all the ads of user with subscription, you can do

```
Ad.joins(:seller_user => :subscriptions)
```

Comment: Thannks a lot !

It's kinda what I want to do !

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some information :

```
Ad.all.collect{|ad| ad unless !(ad.seller_user && ad.seller_user.has_valid_subscripion?)}
```

if yout not do the unless part, you will have a beautiful array of boolean !

But that lead me to what i want !